# How do I properly specify arguments to display a method's output in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(TimeStampedModel):
    fields = #various fields

    def get_some_info(self):
        # returns an output
```

And my admin model looks like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['my_method']

    def my_method(self):
        return self.get_some_info()
...
```

But the admin site shows this error: `my_method() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should take two parameters; `self`: `MyModelAdmin` instance, `obj`: `MyModel` instance.

Replacing `my_method` as following will solve your problem:

```
def my_method(self, obj):
    return obj.get_some_info()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just add `"get_some_info"` directly in `list_display`.